# Java String and Hex character representation

Tags: java, hex, ascii, smpp

I am trying to send a square bracket to a phone using logica smpp 1.3.7.
I use dataCodingSetting of 3 - as per the network I asked about this.
They advised that I need to package my message as below:

```
  You want to send ASCII                Send the following

  Character  Decimal  Hex              Character    Hex     Decimal
     [         91     5B                <ESC><     1B 3C     27 60
```

My question is, I have no clue what this character is: ESC <
And if I put just the Hex value of 1B 3C it comes out on the phone as exactly that: 1B 3C

Comment: What argument type does the method take?

Comment: SubmitSM sm = new SubmitSM();
sm.setShortMessage(content); - content is a String here. So I have a String value that must contain the Hex values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess they want a String containing the bytes 0x1b and 0x3c so :

```
sm.setShortMessage(new String(new byte[] { 0x1b, 0x3c }));
```

Comment: What about `sm.setShortMessage("[" + (char)0x1b + (char)0x3c);`